# Implementation of Dynamic Array with allocators and C++20

Tags: c++, collections, c++20

To train my skills in C++, I decided to implement the well-known "Dynamic array" data structure on my own. I realized early on that using pointers or smart pointers is wrong, as it leads to calling default constructor on reallocation. A naive approach for the `push_back` function would include: `T* new_buf = new T[n]`this is what will call the default constructor of type T. This is the main problem that caused me to start learning allocators.

In the past, I didn't pay much attention to allocators and the probability of throwing an exception (and also `noexcept` specifier). This is my first project that takes these details into account. When programming in C++, it is important for me to follow the best practices and the latest standards.

Next, I will provide my incomplete implementation of the Dynamic array:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <ratio>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace alloc_ext
{
template <class Alloc>
constexpr void destroy(Alloc& alloc, typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer first, const decltype(first) last)
{
    for(; first != last; ++first) {
        std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(alloc, first);
    }
}

template <class Alloc, class InputIt>
constexpr void initialized_rewrite(Alloc& alloc,
    InputIt first,
    InputIt last,
    const typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer d_first)
{
    auto current = d_first;
    try {
        for(; first != last; ++first, (void)++current) {
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(alloc, current);
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, current, *first);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        destroy(alloc, d_first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <class Alloc, class InputIt, class Size>
constexpr void initialized_first_destroy_and_copy(Alloc& alloc,
    InputIt first,
    InputIt last,
    Size destroy_count,
    const typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer d_first)
{
    auto current = d_first;
    try {
        for(; first != last; ++first, (void)++current) {
            if(destroy_count > 0) {
                std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(alloc, current);
                --destroy_count;
            }
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, current, *first);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        destroy(alloc, d_first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <class Alloc>
constexpr void uninitialized_destroy_move(Alloc& alloc,
    typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer first,
    decltype(first) last,
    const decltype(first) d_first)
{
    auto current = d_first;
    try {
        for(; first != last; ++first, (void)++current) {
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, current, std::move(*first));
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy(alloc, first);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        destroy(alloc, d_first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <class Alloc, class InputIt>
constexpr void uninitialized_copy(Alloc& alloc,
    InputIt first,
    InputIt last,
    const typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer d_first)
{
    auto current = d_first;
    try {
        for(; first != last; ++first, (void)++current) {
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, current, *first);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        destroy(alloc, d_first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <class Alloc>
constexpr void uninitialized_default_construct(Alloc& alloc,
    const typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer first,
    const decltype(first) last)
{
    auto current = first;
    try {
        for(; current != last; ++current) {
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, current);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        destroy(alloc, first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <class Alloc>
constexpr void uninitialized_fill(Alloc& alloc,
    const typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer first,
    const decltype(first) last,
    const typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::value_type& value)
{
    auto current = first;
    try {
        for(; current != last; ++current) {
            std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(alloc, current, value);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        destroy(alloc, first, current);
        throw;
    }
}

template <class Alloc>
constexpr void safe_deallocate(Alloc& alloc,
    typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::pointer buf,
    typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type size)
{
    if(size > 0)
        std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::deallocate(alloc, buf, size);
}
}

namespace darray_ns
{
// Implementation of dynamic array. Created by PavelPI 09.12.2021
// Throwing an exception of type std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::value_type
// from the destructor leads to undefined behavior
template <class Allocator, class Ratio = std::ratio<3, 2>> class darray
{
    static_assert(Ratio::num > 0 && Ratio::den > 0 && Ratio::num > Ratio::den);

public:
    using allocator_type = Allocator;

private:
    using alloc_tr = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>;
    using pointer = typename alloc_tr::pointer;

public:
    using ratio = Ratio;
    using value_type = typename alloc_tr::value_type;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using rvalue_reference = value_type&&;
    using const_reference = const value_type&;
    using iterator = typename alloc_tr::pointer;
    using const_iterator = typename alloc_tr::const_pointer;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
    using difference_type = std::iter_difference_t<iterator>;
    using size_type = typename alloc_tr::size_type;

private:
    static constexpr const char* at_out_err = "darray::at(pos) - Attempt to access a non-existent index";

    size_type mcap;
    size_type msize;
    Allocator malloc;
    pointer mbuf;

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr pointer hint_allocate(size_type n)
    {
        if(mcap > 0)
            return alloc_tr::allocate(malloc, n, mbuf + mcap - 1);
        else
            return alloc_tr::allocate(malloc, n);
    }

    constexpr void grow_alloc(size_type new_cap)
    {
        assert(new_cap > 0 && new_cap >= size());
        pointer new_buf = hint_allocate(new_cap);
        constexpr bool is_copyable = std::is_copy_constructible<value_type>::value;
        if constexpr(!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<value_type>::value && is_copyable) {
            try {
                alloc_ext::uninitialized_copy(malloc, mbuf, mbuf + size(), new_buf);
            } catch(...) {
                alloc_tr::deallocate(malloc, new_buf, new_cap);
                throw;
            }
            alloc_ext::destroy(malloc, mbuf, mbuf + size());
        } else {
            try {
                alloc_ext::uninitialized_destroy_move(malloc, mbuf, mbuf + size(), new_buf);
            } catch(...) {
                alloc_tr::deallocate(malloc, new_buf, new_cap);
                throw;
            }
        }
        alloc_ext::safe_deallocate(malloc, mbuf, capacity());
        mbuf = new_buf;
        mcap = new_cap;
    }

    template <bool OtherFill>
    constexpr void internal_resize(size_type new_size,
        std::conditional_t<OtherFill, const_reference, std::tuple<>> value)
    {
        if(size() == new_size)
            return;
        const bool need_grow = new_size > capacity();
        if(need_grow || new_size > size()) {
            if(need_grow)
                grow_alloc(new_size);
            if constexpr(OtherFill)
                alloc_ext::uninitialized_fill(malloc, mbuf + size(), mbuf + new_size, value);
            else
                alloc_ext::uninitialized_default_construct(malloc, mbuf + size(), mbuf + new_size);
        } else
            alloc_ext::destroy(malloc, mbuf + new_size, mbuf + msize);
        msize = new_size;
    }

    template <bool Init, class InputIt> constexpr void internal_assign(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        using tag = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category;
        static_assert(!std::is_same<tag, std::output_iterator_tag>::value);
        if constexpr(std::is_same<tag, std::input_iterator_tag>::value) {
            if constexpr(!Init)
                clear_and_free();
            std::copy(first, last, std::back_inserter(*this));
        } else {
            const size_type new_cap = static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(first, last));
            if(new_cap > capacity() || Init) {
                pointer new_buf = hint_allocate(new_cap);
                try {
                    alloc_ext::uninitialized_copy(malloc, first, last, new_buf);
                } catch(...) {
                    alloc_tr::deallocate(malloc, new_buf, new_cap);
                    throw;
                }
                if constexpr(!Init)
                    destroy_and_dealloc();
                mcap = msize = new_cap;
                mbuf = new_buf;
            } else {
                // new_cap<=capacity && !Init
                if(new_cap <= msize) {
                    alloc_ext::initialized_rewrite(malloc, first, last, mbuf);
                    alloc_ext::destroy(malloc, mbuf + new_cap, mbuf + msize);
                } else
                    alloc_ext::initialized_first_destroy_and_copy(malloc, first, last, msize, mbuf);

                msize = new_cap;
            }
        }
    }

    constexpr void clear_and_free()
    {
        clear();
        alloc_ext::safe_deallocate(malloc, mbuf, capacity());
        mcap = 0;
    }

    constexpr void destroy_and_dealloc()
    {
        alloc_ext::destroy(malloc, mbuf, mbuf + size());
        alloc_ext::safe_deallocate(malloc, mbuf, capacity());
    }

    constexpr size_type next_cap() const
    {
        if(mcap != 0) {
            if constexpr(ratio::den != 1) {
                return static_cast<size_type>((static_cast<std::uintmax_t>(mcap) * ratio::num + ratio::den - 1) /
                    ratio::den); // We are wary of overflow and rounding up
            } else
                return capacity() * ratio::num;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    constexpr static int private_call = 0;
    constexpr darray(size_type init, const Allocator& alloc, int) noexcept
        : mcap(init)
        , msize(init)
        , malloc(alloc)
        , mbuf(alloc_tr::allocate(malloc, init))
    {
    }

public:
    //------------------------------
    //-----CONSTRUCTORS SECTION-----
    //------------------------------
    constexpr explicit darray(const Allocator& alloc) noexcept
        : mcap(0)
        , msize(0)
        , malloc(alloc)
    //, mbuf(nullptr)
    {
    }

    constexpr darray() noexcept(noexcept(Allocator()))
        : darray(Allocator())
    {
    }

    constexpr explicit darray(size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
        : darray(count, alloc, private_call)
    {
        alloc_ext::uninitialized_default_construct(alloc, mbuf, mbuf + size());
    }

    constexpr darray(size_type count, const value_type& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
        : darray(count, alloc, private_call)
    {
        alloc_ext::uninitialized_fill(alloc, mbuf, mbuf + size(), value);
    }

    template <class InputIt>
    constexpr darray(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
        : darray(alloc)
    {
        internal_assign<true>(first, last);
    }

    constexpr darray(const darray& o, const Allocator& alloc)
        : darray(o.begin(), o.end(), alloc)
    {
    }
    constexpr darray(const darray& o)
        : darray(o, alloc_tr::select_on_container_copy_construction(o.malloc))
    {
    }

    constexpr darray(darray&& o) noexcept
        : mcap(std::exchange(o.mcap, 0))
        , msize(std::exchange(o.msize, 0))
        , malloc(std::move(o.malloc))
        , mbuf(std::move(o.mbuf)) // vs std::exchange(o.mbuf, nullptr)
    {
    }
    constexpr darray(darray&& o, const Allocator& alloc) noexcept
        : malloc(alloc)
    {
        if(o.get_allocator() != get_allocator()) {
            msize = mcap = 0;
            // vs mbuf=nullptr;
            internal_assign<true>(std::make_move_iterator(o.first), std::make_move_iterator(o.last));
            o.msize = o.mcap = 0;
            // vs o.mbbuf=nullptr
        } else {
            mcap = std::exchange(o.mcap, 0);
            msize = std::exchange(o.msize, 0);
            mbuf = std::move(o.mbuf); // vs std::exchange(o.mbuf, nullptr);
        }
    }

    constexpr darray(std::initializer_list<value_type> il, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
        : darray(il.begin(), il.end(), alloc)
    {
    }

    constexpr ~darray()
    {
        destroy_and_dealloc();
    }
    //------------------------------
    //-----EDN OF CONSTRUCTORS------
    //------------------------------
    //------------------------------
    //----ELEMENT ACCESS SECTION----
    //------------------------------
    constexpr reference operator[](size_type pos)
    {
        return mbuf[pos];
    }
    constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const
    {
        return mbuf[pos];
    }
    constexpr reference at(size_type pos)
    {
        if(pos < size()) {
            return operator[](pos);
        } else
            throw std::out_of_range(at_out_err);
    }
    constexpr const_reference at(size_type pos) const
    {
        // TODO Duplicate
        if(pos < size()) {
            return operator[](pos);
        } else
            throw std::out_of_range(at_out_err);
    }
    constexpr reference front()
    {
        return *begin();
    }
    constexpr const_reference front() const
    {
        return *cbegin();
    }
    constexpr reference back()
    {
        return *std::prev(end());
    }
    constexpr const_reference back() const
    {
        return *std::prev(cend());
    }
    constexpr pointer data() noexcept
    {
        return mbuf;
    }
    constexpr const pointer data() const noexcept
    {
        return mbuf;
    }
    //------------------------------
    //----END OF ELEMENT ACCESS-----
    //------------------------------

    //------------------------------
    //------ITERATORS SECTION-------
    //------------------------------
    constexpr iterator begin() noexcept
    {
        return mbuf;
    }
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept
    {
        return mbuf;
    }
    constexpr const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return const_cast<const darray&>(*this).begin();
    }
    constexpr iterator end() noexcept
    {
        return mbuf + size();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept
    {
        return mbuf + size();
    }
    constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept
    {
        return const_cast<const darray&>(*this).end();
    }
    // reverse
    constexpr reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept
    {
        return reverse_iterator(end());
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return reverse_iterator(end());
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept
    {
        return const_cast<const darray&>(*this).rbegin();
    }

    constexpr reverse_iterator rend() noexcept
    {
        return reverse_iterator(begin());
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept
    {
        return reverse_iterator(begin());
    }
    constexpr const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept
    {
        return const_cast<const darray&>(*this).rend();
    }
    //------------------------------
    //------END OF ITERATORS--------
    //------------------------------
    //------------------------------
    //------CAPACITY SECTION--------
    //------------------------------
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool empty() const noexcept
    {
        return size() == 0;
    }
    constexpr size_type size() const noexcept
    {
        return msize;
    }
    constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept
    {
        return alloc_tr::max_size(malloc);
    }
    constexpr void reserve(size_type new_cap)
    {
        if(new_cap > mcap) {
            grow_alloc(new_cap);
        }
    }
    constexpr size_type capacity() const noexcept
    {
        return mcap;
    }

    constexpr void shrink_to_fit()
    {
        if(size() == capacity())
            return;
        if(size() != 0)
            grow_alloc(size());
        else
            alloc_ext::safe_deallocate(malloc, mbuf, capacity());
    }
    //------------------------------
    //------END OF CAPACITY --------
    //------------------------------
    //------------------------------
    //-----MODIFIERS SECTION--------
    //------------------------------
    constexpr void clear() noexcept
    {
        alloc_ext::destroy(malloc, mbuf, mbuf + msize); // TODO reverse order is better?
        msize = 0;
    }

    template <class... Args> constexpr reference emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        if(msize >= mcap) {
            grow_alloc(next_cap());
        }
        alloc_tr::construct(malloc, mbuf + msize, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++msize;
        return back();
    }

    constexpr void push_back(const value_type& val)
    {
        emplace_back(val);
    }

    constexpr void push_back(value_type&& val)
    {
        emplace_back(std::move(val));
    }

    constexpr void pop_back() noexcept
    {
        --msize;
        alloc_tr::destroy(malloc, mbuf + msize);
    }

    constexpr void resize(size_type new_size)
    {
        internal_resize<false>(new_size, std::tuple<>());
    }
    constexpr void resize(size_type new_size, const_reference value)
    {
        internal_resize<true>(new_size, value);
    }

    constexpr void swap(darray& o) noexcept(
        alloc_tr::propagate_on_container_swap::value || alloc_tr::is_always_equal::value)
    {
        using std::swap;
        if constexpr(alloc_tr::propagate_on_container_swap::value)
            swap(malloc, o.malloc);
        else {
            if constexpr(!alloc_tr::is_always_equal::value)
                assert(malloc == o.malloc);
        }
        swap(mcap, o.mcap);
        swap(msize, o.msize);
        swap(mbuf, o.mbuf);
    }
    //------------------------------
    //------END OF MODIFIERS--------
    //------------------------------

    //------------------------------
    //---MEMBER FUNCTIONS SECTION---
    //------------------------------
    template <class InputIt> constexpr void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        internal_assign<false>(first, last);
    }
    constexpr void assign(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
    {
        assign(il.begin(), il.end());
    }

    constexpr allocator_type get_allocator() const noexcept
    {
        return malloc;
    }

    darray& operator=(const darray& o)
    {
        if(this != &o) {
            if constexpr(alloc_tr::propagate_on_container_copy_assignment::value) {
                if(malloc != o.malloc) {
                    clear_and_free();
                    malloc = o.malloc;
                }
            }
            assign(o.begin(), o.end());
        }
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr darray& operator=(darray&& o) noexcept(
        alloc_tr::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value || alloc_tr::is_always_equal::value)
    {
        if(this != &o) {
            const auto updater = [&]() {
                destroy_and_dealloc();
                msize = std::exchange(o.msize, 0);
                mcap = std::exchange(o.mcap, 0);
                mbuf = std::move(o.mbuf); // TODO vs std::exchange(o.mbuf,nullptr)
            };
            if constexpr(alloc_tr::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value) {
                updater();
                malloc = std::move(o.malloc); // TODO with move vs without move
            } else {
                if(malloc != o.malloc)
                    assign(std::make_move_iterator(o.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(o.end()));
                else
                    updater();
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr darray& operator=(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
    {
        assign(il.begin(), il.end());
    }
    //------------------------------
    //---END OF MEMBER FUNCTIONS----
    //------------------------------
};
template <class Alloc, class Ratio>
void swap(darray<Alloc, Ratio>& l, darray<Alloc, Ratio>& r) noexcept(noexcept(l.swap(r)))
{
    l.swap(r);
}

template <class Alloc, class Ratio>
constexpr bool operator==(const darray<Alloc, Ratio>& l, const darray<Alloc, Ratio>& r)
{
    if(l.size() != r.size())
        return false;
    return std::equal(l.begin(), l.end(), r.begin());
}

template <class Alloc, class Ratio>
constexpr auto operator<=>(const darray<Alloc, Ratio>& l, const darray<Alloc, Ratio>& r)
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(l.begin(), l.end(), r.begin(), r.end());
}
}
template <class T, class Ratio = std::ratio<3, 2>> using darray = darray_ns::darray<std::allocator<T>, Ratio>;

int main()
{
    //Your code
    //darray<int> d{1,2,3,4,5};
    return 0;
}
```

Be careful, in this implementation, the `insert`/`remove` methods are not implemented yet. Also, I will provide a [link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a176de34e1baca8f) to the playground where `darray` is used.

Any constructive criticism is welcome.